# Difficulty targeting elements in collapsible bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a bootstrap navbar that has 2 collapsible toggle buttons. On small screens, when the 1st one is clicked it shows/hides an unordered list / dropdown menu; when the 2nd one is clicked it shows/hides a search box & submit button. [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lancsdavid/kx55k1bn/10/) shows what happens.

```
<!-- the HTML -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- navbar-header with 2 collapse buttons & the navbar-brand -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- FIRST COLLAPSIBLE DIV -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- end of first collapsed div -->

      <!-- SECOND COLLAPSIBLE DIV -->        
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div><!-- end of second collapsed div -->

    </div><!-- end of container -->
</nav>
```

```
$('.navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    var actives = $(this).find('.collapse.in'),
        hasData;

    if (actives && actives.length) {
        hasData = actives.data('collapse')
        if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
        actives.collapse('hide')
        hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
    }
});
```

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
    float: left;
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2 {
    float: right;
}
```

There is actually a problem with the code even here (even though this isn't the main problem): if you reduce the width of the browser & click either of the toggle buttons you'll see that the dropdown menus that appear (aka 'uncollapsed menus') only take up half the screen. So, how can I (a) target these dropdown elements & (b) assign them appropriate CSS so that they span the full width?

The main problem is a little trickier. On [this](http://passpaeds.com/y/) page you'll see I've tried to apply the solution in the fiddle to an actual website. In this case you'll see that if you reduce the screen width & click both toggle buttons you can actually get both uncollapsed menus on the screen at once. Definitely not what is desired!

The failure here seems to be in the JavaScript/jQuery code (see above & in the fiddle) that supposedly says, IF [there's already uncollapsed menu(s) visible] THEN [collapse them before uncollapsing the other one]. I think. for the [passpaeds.com/y/](http://passpaeds.com/y/) site I've modified this code slightly to display the value of `actives.length` to the console, as I think this is where its falling down.  If you watch firebug's console when you click one then both of the toggle buttons on the [www.passpaeds.com/y/](http://passpaeds.com/y/) site - when the screen width is small enough to have triggered their appearance - you may be able to spot what I'm not doing.